# Django DjangoRestFramework Appending Item to ListField

Tags: python, arrays, django, string, django-rest-framework

I faced this problem while appending a `CharField` item to `ListField`: the result list is split into individual characters instead of one string. The files:

```py
# serializers.py

class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    key = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')
    levels = serializers.ListField(source='level')    # (a)

    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ['key', 'title', 'desc', 'level', 'levels', 'created']
```

(a):

```py
# models.py
level = models.CharField(_('level'), max_length=20)
```

What I want the `ListField` to behave is, say the level is `normal`, I want the ListField to come out as `["normal"]`. However, it came out as individual characters, as shown in this image:
[image]

In one sentence, I want to append `level` into `levels` but the format is not satisfactory.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to show as an array with only `level` value?, is that correct?, is going to be readonly?

Comment: Doesn't have to be read-only, but everything else, yes

Comment: What about `SerializerMethodField` ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu agree that is a good solution if the field is read only

Comment: I didn't notice that point mentioned in the OP. @cabesuon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this could be using a custom field. Something like this,

```
class LevelsField(serializers.Field):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return [value.level]

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # here you need to implement your transform logic
        return ','.join(data)
```

Then you use it like this,

```
levels = LevelsField(source='*')
```

[DRF Docs - Serializers - Custom Fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields)